# adding ojdbc6.jar to maven local repository

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, maven, m2e

I have not installed maven in my local PC manually. I am using inbuilt maven that comes with eclipse EE ide. I have known that ojdbc6.jar is not available in maven central repository. So how can i install it to my local repository. I have tried "mvn install:install-file" command in cmd. As i have not installed maven it is saying ('mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.).
1) Is there any way to add ojdbc6 to local repository without installing maven in my pc.
2) Do I have to compulsorily install maven in my PC to add ojdbc6 into my local repository.
 I have tried to uninstall maven plugin in my eclipse but it is not uninstalling.
3)So even if I install maven in my PC and manually configure it in my eclipse will it work or will there be any errors because built-in maven in eclipse and local maven may give some error.
Trust me I have searched in web to solve this issue. I have found solutions only for manually installed maven but not for builtin maven in eclipse.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can call any goal from the built in maven from eclipse (which is called m2e, by the way), by using `Run As -> Maven build ...` on the project (or the `pom.xml`).

Then you just write the goal without the `mvn`, i.e. in your case, you just write `install:install-file`. The parameters can entered in the list that is visible in the lower part of the dialog.